# Simple tool for backup VPS to Amazon Glacier

Tags: debian, backup, database-backups, amazon-glacier

**Intro:**
I have VPS (with Debian) and some websites that hosted on it. Sites are not very large (~10-20 GB totally) but I need to make periodic backups of all user data.

**Problem:**
I'm looking for simple solutions that allows to backup all this stuff to  Amazon Glacier, and meet some conditions:

1. Easy to configure (because I'm newbie in server administration)
2. Amazon Glacier support
3. Debian support
4. Backup all files (entirely /home directory)
5. Incremental weekly backups

I've found some solutions like http://www.bacula.org/en/ but they aren't so easy to manage.

Could you give advice for my case or recommend good tools for such backups?

Comment: what have you tried so far? how did the expected output differ from the actual output? you might read the [faq] on how to ask which question.

Comment: I've searched a lot, but can't find really simple solution. There are very feature-rich  such a [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/), but I actually don't need  RAID support, GUI etc. I'm looking for tool  that just can backup to Glacier whole VPS (/home directory i mean).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Use duplicity to backup to local filesystem (and implement weekly, incremental backups).
2. Use this client https://github.com/vsespb/mt-aws-glacier for incremental backups of duplicity output into Amazon Glacier.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find is [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) but I'm not sure if it is ready for Glacier. Hopefully the following blog post might provide additional information:

- [Using duplicity with Amazon Glacier](http://blog.epsilontik.de/?page_id=68)

Comment: Thx, but dublicity currently doesn't support Glacier. I think about hybrid approach: perform backups to local filesystem and upload it to Glacier using smth like [backthat](https://github.com/tsileo/bakthat).  But there is a question how to upload only changes (for incremental backups)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but just for the record I developed a tool to periodic send data to AWS Glacier, you can check it at:

https://github.com/rafaeljusto/toglacier

If you have any suggestion or found a problem please fill free to open an issue or send a PR. =)